# ASDF output redirection

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp, asdf

I would like to set directory where ASDF stores compiled files. I prefer to do it from a shell script. According to [this page](http://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf/Output-Shell_002dfriendly-syntax-for-configuration.html#Output-Shell_002dfriendly-syntax-for-configuration), one should define environment variable `ASDF_OUTPUT_TRANSLATIONS`.

OK, here it is:

```
$ export ASDF_OUTPUT_TRANSLATIONS="$HOME/.cache/common-lisp/my-dir/"
```

But when I try to test the configuration, it does not work:

```
$ clisp -x "(asdf:compile-system :my-system)"
```

Output:

```
;; Loading file /home/mark/.clisprc.lisp ...
;;  Loading file /home/mark/quicklisp/setup.lisp ...
*** - Uneven number of components in source to destination mapping:
      "/home/mark/.cache/common-lisp/my-dir/"
Bye.
```

Bye. Well, it's one of possible outputs. I've tried to assign lots of values to `ASDF_OUTPUT_TRANSLATIONS`. Even and odd. Small and big. No success. This would be *way* easier if there is an example of such configuration, but I could not find one.

Another problem is that I don't know if systems which will be compiled will not overwrite files with the same names of each other when ASDF puts everything into one directory. What I really want is temporarily setting of output directory from shell script, so every file would be in predictable place no matter where source files are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I succeeded with the following:

```
$ export ASDF_OUTPUT_TRANSLATIONS="/:$HOME/.cache/common-lisp/my-dir/"
```

**Note 1**: destination directory may not exist: in this case ASDF will create it.

**Note 2**: one cannot use symbols like `*` or `**` in this string. Directory `/` denotes all possible directories.

**Note 3**: ASDF will create subdirectories inside of `my-dir` like this:

```
/home/mark/.cache/common-lisp/my-dir/home/mark/path/to/source/files/
```

It is not exactly what I wanted, but since I can detect where source files are located before building takes place by placing them into subdirectory of the directory where my shell script is located, it's not a critical problem.

Answer (score 0):

The way I read http://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf/Controlling-where-ASDF-saves-compiled-files.html, you need to put a mapping there that specifies a match and a translation.  In the sexp syntax, you can specify it as `(t "/home.../...dir/")`, where `t` means matching all.

You can also use functions to translate the directories:

```
(t (:function (lambda (dir) #|translate dir as you like|#)))
```

Also read about where to put such directives.  The environment variable seems to be treated by some special syntax that I have not completely understood.  You could use configuration files instead if it doesn't work out.

*edit:* Sorry, just reading the documentation (which really has room for improvement) http://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf/Output-Configuration-DSL.html.  You might need to be a bit more explicit:

```
(:output-translations (t "/foo/bar"))
```

The corresponding "shell friendly" syntax might be like this:

```
**/:/foo/bar
```

Comment: Invalid asdf output-translation (T "/home/mark/.cache/common-lisp/my-dir/") (will be skipped). Also tried pathnames instead of strings and wrapping this list with another one. No result. I need to do it *temporarily*, in shell script. Environment variable is way better than configuration files in my case.

Comment: Can't reliably convert wild pathname #P"**/". Tried your suggestion and many more variations. What a pain...