# Win10: ASDF can't load system (ASDF_OUTPUT_TRANSLATION error)

Tags: windows-10, common-lisp, sbcl, pathname, asdf

### Update 2

I think @faré is right, it's an output translation problem.

So I declared the evironment variable `ASDF_OUTPUT_TRANSLATIONS` and set it to `E:/`. Now `(asdf:require-system "my-system")` yields a different error: `Uneven number of components in source to destination mapping: "E:/"` which led me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25323394/asdf-output-redirection) SO-topic.

Unfortunately, his solution doesn't work for me. So I tried the other answer and set `ASDF_OUTPUT_TRANSLATIONS` to `(:output-translations (t "E:/"))`. Now I get yet another error:

```
Invalid source registry (:OUTPUT-TRANSLATIONS (T "E:/")).
One and only one of
    :INHERIT-CONFIGURATION or
    :IGNORE-INHERITED-CONFIGURATION
is required.
(will be skipped)
```

### Original Posting

I have a simple system definition but can't get ASDF to load it.
(asdf-version 3.1.5, sbcl 1.3.12 (**upgraded to 1.3.18 AMD64**), slime 2.19, Windows 10)

### What I have tried so far

#### Following the ASDF manual: *"4.1 Configuring ASDF to find your systems"*

There it says:

> For Windows users, and starting with ASDF 3.1.5, start from your
>   %LOCALAPPDATA%, which is usually ~/AppData/Local/ (but you can ask in
>   a CMD.EXE terminal echo %LOCALAPPDATA% to make sure) and underneath
>   create a subpath config/common-lisp/source-registry.conf.d/

That's exactly what I did:

1. Echoing `%LOCALAPPDATA%` which evaluates to `C:\Users\my-username\AppData\Local`
2. Underneath I created the subfolders config\common-lisp\source-registry.conf.d\ (In total: `C:\Users\my-username\AppData\Local\config\common-lisp\source-registry.conf.d\`

The manual continues:

> there create a file with any name of your choice but with the type conf, for instance `50-luser-lisp.conf`; in this file, add the following line to tell ASDF to recursively scan all the subdirectories under /home/luser/lisp/ for .asd files: (:tree "/home/luser/lisp/")
>   That’s enough. You may replace /home/luser/lisp/ by wherever you want to install your source code.

In the **source-registry.conf.d** folder I created the file **my.conf** and put in it `(:tree "C:/Users/my-username/my-systems/")`. This folder contains a **my-system.asd**.

#### And here comes the weird part:

If I now type `(asdf:require-system "my-system")` in the REPL I get the following error:
Can't create directory `C:\Users\my-username\AppData\Local\common-lisp\sbcl-1.3.12-win-x86\C\Users\my-username\my-systems\C:\`

So the problem is not that ASDF doesn't find the file, it does -- but (whatever the reason) it tries to create a really weird subfolder hierarchy which ultimately fails because at the end it tries to create the folder `C:` but Windows doesn't allow foldernames containing a colon.

#### Another approach: `(push path asdf:*central-registry*)`

If I try

```
> (push #P"C:/Users/my-username/my-systems/" asdf:*central-registry*)
(#P"C:/Users/my-username/my-systems/"
 #P"C:/Users/my-username/AppData/Roaming/quicklisp/quicklisp/")

> (asdf:require-system "my-system")
```

I get the exact same error.

I don't know what to do.

### Update

Because of the nature of the weird path ASDF was trying to create I thought maybe I could bypass the problem by specifying a relative path instead of an absolute one.
So I tried
  `(:tree "\\Users\\my-username\\my-systems")`
in my conf file. Still the same error.

Comment: It seems that ASDF tries to create the location for FASL files. This location starts in AppData folder and to distinguish between different lisps and sources it recreates the full path to source. Now, in my installation it manages to remove colon from "C:". To sidestep the problem (if it is acceptable): QUICKLISP should help.

Comment: What do you mean bei 'Quicklisp should help'? Can I make quicklisp load my asd file? (I have quicklisp installed)

Comment: Yes, put the directory with your system into `local-projects`, run `(ql:register-local-systems)` and then `(ql:quickload :your-system)`.

Comment: Ok, this is weird. It says `Loading "my-system"` and then again the same error.

Comment: Can you load other systems via QUICKLISP? it's something really weird with ASDF...

Comment: Also, check the value of ` asdf:*user-cache*` - that is where ASDF is putting FASLs. If it contains a weird path, re-assign it. If it fixes the issue, you may want to add the assignment to this variable into your `.sbclrc` file.

Comment: Can we see the contents of `my-system.asd` ? Are you trying to use absolute pathnames within a system definition???

Answer (score 2):

Ahem. It looks like an output-translations problem.

I don't have a Windows machine right now, but this all used to work last time I tried.

Can you setup some ad hoc output-translations for now that will make it work?

Comment: Also, can you confirm that the problem still happens with the latest ASDF 3.2.1 and the latest SBCL 1.3.18 ?

Comment: Finally, the asdf-devel mailing-list is a better place to seek help about ASDF.

Comment: I uninstalled sbcl 1.3.12 and installed 1.3.18. I set up emacs from scratch. Still the same error but I still have ASDF 3.1.5. What is the best way to upgrade ASDF? (I really appreciate your help.)

Comment: Ok, updated ASDF to 3.2.1. Still the same error. Nonetheless, thanks for trying to help.

Comment: I don't understand how c: ends up in the filename position.

Comment: Can you

`(require "asdf")
(trace asdf::apply-output-translations asdf::output-files)`

Comment: Also, what is the .asd for the failing system? Do you fail on all systems or only a specific one? One you wrote or a free software system?

Comment: Did you see my **Update 2** in the OP? I am past the `c:` in the file name problem. It's now about `INHERIT-CONFIGURATION`. If I do `(trace asdf::apply-output-translations asdf::output-files) ` I get the same error as described in Update 2 of my OP: `Invalid source registry (:OUTPUT-TRANSLATIONS (T "E:/")). One
and only one of :INHERIT-CONFIGURATION or
:IGNORE-INHERITED-CONFIGURATION is required.
(will be skipped)`